# rxjs subscription not triggering

Tags: reactjs, rxjs

```
import { Subject } from "rxjs";

export const chatstream$ = new Subject();
```

The subscription to subject not triggering if i dont instantiate another useobservable const

ex:(this refreshes the values (25 total))

```
   const value = useObservable(() => interval(1000).pipe(map(val => val + 1)));
   const subscriptionchatstream: any = useObservable(() => chatstream$.pipe(map(val => {
        console.log(val)
        return val})));
```

if I dont add the value there is only 1 entry on subscription.(error case, so chatstream content is missing not refreshing)

```
const subscriptionchatstream: any = useObservable(() => chatstream$.pipe(map(val => {
            console.log(val)
            return val})));
```

How can i make the subscription make refreshe itself on every new without error?

Comment: could you share the whole function?

Comment: check code https://codeshare.io/G8ERPe